# Mysql help updating rows with price from other ID

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with setting a price for a product based on another ID

Currently we have say..**productX** with a price of **0**.
Then we have a **productZ** with a price of say **10**

ProductX has a reference to the ID of ProductY in the table. SO any products with a reference of the other product via the ID should update the price from the other product. If that makes sense?

Thank you, kind regards Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this update query,

```
UPDATE product_test AS t1, (
    SELECT id, price
    FROM product_test
) AS t2
SET t1.price = t2.price
WHERE t1.new_id = t2.id;
```

Hope it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all of them with new_id set to the same price you could:

```
UPDATE pricing SET price = '7.00' WHERE new_id NOT NULL;
```

Assuming price is a string etc.

Comment: Hi Cherryade Thanks for that. But we dont want a static value of 7.00. We want to update the id of any row with a new_id value present and take the new_ids price

Comment: Something like this...but it doesnt work UPDATE product_test SET price = ( SELECT product_test.price
WHERE product_test.product_id = product_test.new_id AND product_test.new_id IS NOT NULL)